# Call a function is JavaScript that calls a promise function and returns the result to the original function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have two functions (One function within the controller and oen function in a service). I want to call the service function from the controller function. After calling teh service function this function calls a database function (using Sequelize).

Controller:

```
exports.getMilestoneById = async (req, res, next) => {
    const milestoneId = req.params.milestoneId;
    try{
    milestoneService.getMilestoneById(milestoneId)
    .then(mielstone => {
        console.log("Milestone in tehn: " + mielstone)
    });
    console.log("Milestone: " + milestone);
    res.status(200).json({message: 'Milestone fetched', milestone: milestone});
    } catch (error){
        if (!error.statusCode){
            error.statusCode = 500;
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
exports.getMilestoneById = async (milestoneId) => {

Milestone.findByPk(milestoneId)
.then(milestone => {
    console.log("In Service: " + milestone)
    return milestone.get();
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log("Error" + err);
});
```

}

The problem: I don't get a milestone back.

Comment: You already have your functions `async`, so let's use that! `const milestone = await milestoneService.getMilestoneById(milestoneId)` without `then`. Also, `const milestone = await Milestone.findByPk(milestoneId)`, again without `then`, and it will work.

Comment: I would recommend not mixing `.then()` Promise handling with `async/await` style coding. If it's an `async` function, then `await` the function calls that return promises; that's the whole point of the new syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's try to put some order here.

##### Promises Flow

Your code doesn't wait for the `Promise` response.

```
milestoneService.getMilestoneById(milestoneId) // <- this returns a promise
// all stuff below here doesn't wait for the promise to complete and can't see its result
console.log("Milestone: " + milestone);
res.status(200).json({message: 'Milestone fetched', milestone: milestone});
```

Instead, writing something like:

```
milestoneService.getMilestoneById(milestoneId)
    .then(mielstone => {
        console.log("Milestone in tehn: " + mielstone);
        // I moved all the stuff that needs to wait in here!!
        console.log("Milestone: " + milestone);
        res.status(200).json({message: 'Milestone fetched', milestone: milestone});
    });
```

This would work as expected.

##### Async / Await

You added that `async` before the functions, I'd figure you could put that to good use!
`async / await` helps you clean the promises flow by letting the wrapping function wait for their results, so writing something like:

```
    const milestone = await milestoneService.getMilestoneById(milestoneId)
    console.log("Milestone: " + milestone);
    res.status(200).json({message: 'Milestone fetched', milestone: milestone});
```

Would also work as expected.

##### Returns

... or not! You missed pretty much all returns in your code. As a rule of thumbs try to make every function always return something, especially if it's promises! So like:

```
exports.getMilestoneById = async (milestoneId) => {
 const milestone = await Milestone.findByPk(milestoneId);
 return milestone.get();
 /* I don't suggest handling the error here, because it doesn't bubble well! 
 /* If there's an error what would this function return?
}
```

Then

```
exports.getMilestoneById = async (req, res, next) => {
    const milestoneId = req.params.milestoneId;
    try {
       const milestone = await milestoneService.getMilestoneById(milestoneId)
       console.log("Milestone: " + milestone);
        // just return this
       return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Milestone fetched', milestone });
    } catch (error){
        if (!error.statusCode){
            error.statusCode = 500;
        }
        // call next with the error!
        return next(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are returning the result in this callback:

```js
.then(milestone => {
    console.log("In Service: " + milestone)
    return milestone.get();
})
```

You are in fact setting the return value for the callback function, not the return value for your service function `milestone service.getMilestoneById()`.
Because your function is an `async` function, you should use Javascript's async-await syntax, which will only get the value once the promise is resolved.

```js
exports.getMilestoneById = async (milestoneId) => {
    const milestone = await Milestone.findByPk(milestoneId)
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error" + err);
    });

    console.log("In Service: " + milestone)
    return milestone
}
```

This should be the same for your controller function:

```js
exports.getMilestoneById = async (req, res, next) => {
    const milestoneId = req.params.milestoneId;
    try{
    const milestone = await milestoneService.getMilestoneById(milestoneId)
    console.log("Milestone: " + milestone);
    res.status(200).json({message: 'Milestone fetched', milestone: 
    milestone});
    } catch (error){
        if (!error.statusCode){
            error.statusCode = 500;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest handling the promise `catch` in `getMilestoneById` because that way the function would return `undefined` when erroring instead of bubbling up the error.

Comment: Thank you both so much! Now it works really well. But now I have a short additional question: How / Where should I handle the error, if there is no Milestone with the milestoneId? I get an error message because of the"return milestone.get();", and get is not possible. But it would be quite nice if I could define an error that descripes that the requested milestone doesn't exist.

Comment: put `if(!milestone) throw new Error('No milestone found with the given ID')` right before the `return milestone.get()`. As a rule of thumbs try to spot the possible issues as early as you can (so right after you queried the milestone, check if it exists) and throw a meaningful error for that condition.